# Nativescript returns a "Error: ADB server didn't ACK" message while trying to run on device

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, adb, nativescript

I'm trying to run a nativescript app on my device but I get the below. I'm using windows and things I've tried include;

1. Killing and restarting adb server
2. Checking port 5037 for processes using it and killing it (although I find that it's being used by adb.exe anyway)
3. Re-Installed NodeJS
4. Tried several versions of NodeJs
5. Tried setting the PATH variables again (just to make sure)
6. Replaced the adb.exe in the platform-tools directory
7. I've also tried deleting the .android config folder

I've tried the app on other systems and it runs well. So I know the problem isn't from the application. I'm currently using node v4.4.5

`Error: ADB server didn't ACK
    * failed to start daemon *
    error: cannot connect to daemon: No error
    error: cannot connect to daemon: No error
        at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\mobile\mobile-core\android-device-discovery.js:54:25)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
        at Pipe.onread (net.js:531:20)
    Sending exception report (press Ctrl+C to stop)...`

Comment: Dupe. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22264030/2543566

Comment: Hi @VictorNascimento I have tried several solutions from SO and I listed them above. I've obviously tried killing the process using the port (please see list) Thanks though. If others have an answer marked as a solution and they don't work for me then I don't consider this a duplicate since chances of me clinging onto the thread and getting an answer is pretty slim.