# Daemon not running. Starting it now on port 5037

Tags: android, android-studio, command, adb, android-sdk-tools

```
[2014-04-16 14:01:05 - Abc] ------------------------------
[2014-04-16 14:01:05 - Abc] Android Launch!
[2014-04-16 14:01:05 - Abc] The connection to `ADB` is down, and a severe error has occurred.
[2014-04-16 14:01:05 - Abc] You must restart `ADB` and Eclipse.
[2014-04-16 14:01:05 - Abc] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

The above error has occurred while I was trying to run a program. As a solution,

I did the following steps by opening the command prompt :

- Close the Eclipse if running
- Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
- type `adb kill-server`
- then type `adb start-server`
- No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then `adb is started successfully`.
- Now you can start Eclipse again.

but it is not working and in the command prompt it shows :

```
daemon not running .starting it now on port 5037 ADB server didn't ACK FAILED TO START DAEMON
```

Comment: That almost sounds like security software or something could be blocking the two "halves" of ADB from talking to each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adb won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306322/adb-wont-start)

Comment: Solved the issue with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70915818/5935112

Answer (score 28):

Reference link: http://www.programering.com/a/MTNyUDMwATA.html

Steps I followed
1) Execute the command `adb nodaemon server` in command prompt
   Output at command prompt will be: The following error occurred cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
The original ADB server port binding failed

2) Enter the following command query which using port 5037
`netstat -ano | findstr "5037"`
The following information will be prompted on command prompt: TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 9288

3) View the task manager, close all adb.exe

4) Restart eclipse or other IDE

The above steps worked for me.

Comment: i don't know why this answer is not accepted... working awesome

Comment: How do I fix this for a mac?

Comment: @AdamHurwitz -- oh that's easy. Trade the MAC for a PC. Done! -- sorry couldn't resist.

Comment: Worked for me. That's pure FM.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:
Open task manager (of your OS) and kill adb.exe process. Now start adb again, now adb should start normally.