# Android Studio - no Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run my new Project in Android Studio. I want to run it on emulator. I created the new virtual device but Android Studio doesn't see this device. I created ~10 devices with various configuration and problem still exists. My project was created on API 23. When I run AVD  Manager from sdk folder it showing up every device that I created...  Below I attach the screens of this problem. Can someone help me?

p.s. When I changed the target in 'Edit configurations', then my project works, but I would to have a opportunity to test it on various configurations without edit configurations all the time..

Android studio:
[image]

AVD Manager from sdk folder:
[image]

Comment: You might want to navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools (or similar) on your command line tool and run the `adb devices` command. It's output might show the error you've encountered. Source: [link](http://visualgdb.com/KB/?ProblemID=noandroiddev)

Comment: It's result of this command: http://i.imgur.com/c7Aq5Tg.png

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231025/5244435

Comment: @sup4eli Thanks to this link I found the solution! I followed those steps, but still didn't work. Then tried to kill SQL Reporting Services and it's working! Thanks a lot! Maybe put it into answer then I mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are several sources that explain how to properly setup a AVD - android virtual device, this might be a good idea to check official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html#createavd).

- The basic steps:

  1. In Visual Studio select Android -> AVD Manager.
  2. In AVD Manager press "New".
  3. Enter a device name and select a target. Please use Android 2.3.3 or newer. Older versions are not stable and might not work.
  4. Press "Create AVD"
  5. Press "Start"
  6. Wait till your device starts up.

If you do get into "no android devices found" on the AVD manager you would want to retrieve some more info with the following steps:

1. Open command-line tool.
2. Go to platform-tools directory in your Android SDK directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, )
3. Run the `adb devices` command.
   [Credit goes to this article](http://visualgdb.com/KB/?ProblemID=noandroiddev)

The output might give a clue regarding the cause.
In your case i was able to find the following post on SO that deals with similar issue, [review it here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104394/daemon-not-running-starting-it-now-on-port-5037/26231025#26231025).

Comment: Thanks for help, I add only one thing: If solution `adb nodaemon server` works (executiong without error) and you have to run it every time when you run virtual device, try to run Android Studio as administrator. For me works combination of the above solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to start the device on which you would like to deploy your app before starting your app.

This way this device will appear in the deployments target should your app be compatible according to its manifest's `minSdkVersion` field.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfortunately still doesn't work. I don't know what to do, yesterday I updated Android Studio from 2.1 to 2.2.2 version. Before this update it worked perfect.