# Error daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

Tags: java, android, mobile, daemon

I was testing a code on my cellphone and it worked nice. When i switched to another cellphone, also keep working, but when I went back to my initial cellphone, the current error appear on the logcat, and the app closes down when it starts.

```
daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
daemon started successfully
```

If you have any ideas how to solve it, consider that I'm really newbie, so if possible explain to me how to solve step by step.

Comment: you would need to include more context about how to reproduce your issue, what about the specific code you are testing?

Comment: it's a pretty large code. I think the problem is in the Android Studio.

Comment: Have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23104394/833336