# ADB server can't start android

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I have installed adt bundle eclipse. However, I can't seems to run the AVD. I have the problem of

```
ADB server didn't ACK 
failed to start daemon
```

I have search on how to solve it, I've read to type `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`. when I typed that, it says

```
adb server is out of date. killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *"
```

Comment: which OS do you have?

Comment: also which SDK version

Comment: have you updated your SDK to the latest version?

Comment: no, my school project requires API 16 and Nexus S

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adb won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306322/adb-wont-start)

Answer (score 4):

Please follow below steps:-

1. Go to run
2. open command prompt
3. get into your **platform-tools** under android **sdk**.
4. now type command: **adb kill-server**
5. then upon success type: **adb start-server**

Thats'it.

Let me know if you still facing any issue..

Comment: yes i did, and it says "adb server is out of date. killing... ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon *"

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you running and what is the OS version on the device you are debugging?

What you might need to do is actually downgrade your version of the SDK tools so that the ADB daemon and process are in agreement. I thought the server process was completely backward compatible, but this could be one of those corner cases where it doesn't. Google doesn't advertise the fact that you can get their old SDK tools packages, but they can be found by looking in the archives area at http://developer.android.com.

Comment: API 16 and Nexus S if that is what you're asking

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact problem on my Vista x64 system. I solved it by doing the following:
Ctrl-Alt-Del, start Task Manager, under Processes tab, check for "shuame_helper.exe". It was there from running RootGenius. I clicked End Process, then went back to the command prompt and entered adb start-server and it worked!

Comment: Nothing there like "shuame_helper.exe" :(

Answer (score 1):

Try below step from DDMS in eclipse   :

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for replying, but i got another error: Adb failed to restart! Make sure the plugin is properly configured.

Comment: r u sure ur debug option is checked?

Comment: which device u hv and which os?

Comment: Nexus S and API 16 if that's what you're asking, and oh, i've found another way to solve it: go to the process and stop adb.exe, but the problem is, i dont have an adb.exe, idk why

Comment: and which OS ? windows ?ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem and failed in all the same ways as above:

adb kill-server
followed by 
adb start-server

still resulted in the ADB server didn't ACK error.

The other common suggestion of using the task manager to kill the process also 
failed as it seemed that something restarted adb automatically? It would disappear for a second, then there were two adb processes ,then there was one again.

Exasperated.

I restarted Windows in safe mode.

This ensured that adb wasn't started. 
Shut down and restart normally. Problem solved.

Just for good measure, I also updated eclipse and android at this point, but I think that the safe mode restart fixed it.

Give it a try when all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens I open Activity Monitor (on mac) or Task Manager (on windows) and look for the ADB process and force close it (sometimes there are more than one, close those to) and then press the Run button again in Android Studio or Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

1)Open task manager first
2)close any instance of adb.exe(end task it)
3)open command prompt
4) type adb start-server(you may have to execute it twice)
5) try to run now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using the latest ADT, SDK and Eclipse on Windows 7. I had an old ASUS TF101 and an HTC HD connected with their respective docking software. When I looked in processor tab of the Windows task manager I could see two instances of the adb.exe, one loaded and another one looking like it is trying to load.

I killed the PC connecting software (process in task manager) for the ASUS, the HTC Sync wasn't running. There is now one adb.exe running and both devices are recognised in Eclipse and in the command prompt (adb devices). You may need to restart Eclipse.