# Eclipse doesn't recognize my android 4.4.2

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android BQ Aquaris E5 HD with the version 4.4.2 and when I plug it on my mac, the android file manager launch and it's all ok, but when I run my android app from eclipse my phone doesn't appear on the devices list to run the app.
But if I try for example with a Samsung SIII it works fine

What can be wrong here ?

Comment: go to  ddms and there is down arrow there is otion called reset adb..look at the my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824214/adb-server-cant-start-android

Comment: sorry can you be more specific ? I'm new on this things

Comment: Check the phone screen.  Each time I use adb on a new computer, my 4.4 phone asks if I want to allow it.

Comment: what ur code min and max sdk version in manifest?

Comment: the min is 14 and the max is 19...

Comment: I've tried to reset adb from eclipse and i got this error: "[2014-08-04 18:17:22 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-08-04 18:17:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-08-04 18:17:22 - ddms] '/Users/Goncalo/Documents/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary"

Answer (score 2):

I also have a BQ E5, but the FHD version.

Try this:

1) Install ADB Driver Installer and make sure your device appears in this software screen.
http://adbdriver.com/

2) Go to Eclipse

3) Go to Windows / Open Perspective / DDMS

4) In the screen that appears, to the left of the tab where it says "Threads" there is a small triangle up-side-down "View Menu"

5) Select "reset adb"

6) Accept in your phone the message of authorization

Your device should appear now and be available.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, same device (BQ Aquaris 5 HD), same Android version (4.4.2), also a mac (@Serge answer is for Windows OS I think) . I found the solution following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136003/3933088) from user [dustmachine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76941/dustmachine) in another topic.

Follow the steps about editing the adb_usb.ini, in my case the vendor ID was 0x2a47 but check it yourself just in case.

The command **echo 0x2a47 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini** did not work for me for some reason. If that happens to you, go to your home folder (terminal will open there by default, or just execute the command **cd**) and execute the command **ls -a** to see the hidden files and check that the .android folder exists. Go in (**cd .android**) and execute **echo 0x2a47 >> adb_usb.ini** and it should work just fine. You can check it for example with pico (**pico adb_usb.ini**).

Now reset adb. In my case as I don't have it as an environment variable, I went to the folder where the adb program is, inside the sdk. It should be something like **/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/**. Just look for it around, should be easy. To reset the adb execute the command **./adb kill-server** (or just **adb kill-server** if you have adb as a environment variable) and then **./adb devices**. It should restart the daemon. Plug your Aquaris and execute **./adb devices** again. If everything went well, it should appear now.

One more thing. It should appear now in your mobile phone a pop-up with an advice about debugging from that computer. If you don't accept it the device will appear as offline and unelectable when prompt to pick device in eclipse, for example. If you accept the device will finally be available for debugging as when you work with the emulator.

Sorry if I explained some obvious steps, but I encountered a ton of problems with small things like those while finding the solution.

If you still encounter problems, be sure that you have set your device to debugging mode ([the seven build-number tap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364131)). Check this questions for more detailed information:

[How to load my app from Eclipse to my Android phone instead of AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992357/how-to-load-my-app-from-eclipse-to-my-android-phone-instead-of-avd)

[adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have USB Debugging turned on?

go to **settings -> Developer options ->** and turn on **USB Debugging**.

Comment: Yes I have... So I think it's weird

Comment: and in notifications center i have the message that says "USB debugginh connected"

Answer (score 0):

MAC Yosemite with Bq Aquaris E10 3G Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

1) Disconnect USB from MAC

2) echo 0x2a47 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

3) adb kill-server

4) CONNECT TABLET to MAC using USB

5) adb devices