# can't connect my android device to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to connect my device to android studio but it doesn't detect it, no matter what I try. My device is an Aquaris E5 and is running android 4.4.4. 
I want to use it as test device for my apps. 
I'm on a mac computer running os x 10.9.4 and it seems like it's a device problem, because I've tried with another device (jiayu jy-G4) running android 4.2.1 and works just fine. 
I've enabled usb depuration in the developer menu and according to google this is all I need to do. My android studio is up to date and I've downloaded all the skd's, plugins, etc... 
So I'm a bit confused, and also new on this, so I don't know what else to try. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123428/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-my-android-4-4-2

Comment: open terminal in android-studio execute these cmd maybe usefull- ./adb kill-server and ./adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

To see some devices ( especially not that well know vendors ) you need to add the vendor-id in .android/adb_usb.ini
Under linux you can use:

```
lsusb
```

to get the vendor id. then you have do to:

```
adb kill-server
```

to see the device.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

For Test only : test if you mac recognise your phone by installing [Android USB for MAC](https://www.android.com/filetransfer)

Answer (score 0):

> Enable debugging over USB.
>
> Open the Developer options in the system Settings. On Android 4.2 and
>   higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it
>   visible, go to Settings  About phone and tap Build number seven times.
>   Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

If already have this option on,

Try this:

1) Install ADB Driver Installer and make sure your device appears in this software screen. http://adbdriver.com/

2) Go to Eclipse

3) Go to Windows / Open Perspective / DDMS

4) In the screen that appears, to the left of the tab where it says "Threads" there is a small triangle up-side-down "View Menu"

5) Select "reset adb"

6) Accept in your phone the message of authorization