# ionic cannot emulate android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using ionic and I am trying to emulate android but I got an error

```
Error executing "adb devices": ADB server didn't ACK

* failed to start daemon *

error: unknown host service


Error: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat:
 Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\HP USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

and here is the full output

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1>ionic emulate android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\xampp\htdocs\android_proj
ects\test1\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js c:\xampp\htdocs\android
_projects\test1
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\cordov
a\run.bat --emulator
Buildfile: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5
 [checkenv] Installed at J:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5
 [checkenv] Installed at J:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: CordovaApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\
test1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms
\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\a
ndroid\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\p
latforms\android\ant-build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed
in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use
-Xlint:-options.
    [javac] 3 warnings

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\ant-
build\classes
      [dex] input: C:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\Cord
ovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-2de3274ed2db2dc2fdd48481de377584.jar <- C:\x
ampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classe
s.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into c:\xampp\htdoc
s\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\ant-build\classes.dex...
       [dx] Merged dex A (12 defs/8.7KiB) with dex B (209 defs/316.7KiB). Result
 is 221 defs/395.4KiB. Took 0.1s

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\
test1\platforms\android\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms
\android\ant-build\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
[apkbuilder] Creating CordovaApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug
 key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\andr
oid\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\pl
atforms\android\ant-build\build.prop

-post-build:
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\an
droid\ant-build
     [move] Moving 1 file to c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\an
droid\CordovaLib\ant-build

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
Built the following apk(s):
    c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaAp
p-debug.apk

c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\
q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error executing "adb devices": ADB server didn't ACK

* failed to start daemon *

error: unknown host service


Error: c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat:
 Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\HP USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

c:\xampp\htdocs\android_projects\test1>
```

**How can I solve this please?**

Thanks

Comment: Adb kill-server and then adb devices

Answer (score 0):

This is not a ionic framework problem. 
Your system is not able to run adb deamon.

Checkout the below links for solution :

1. [ADB server can't start android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824214/adb-server-cant-start-android)
2. [Eclipse error "ADB server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/my-eclipse-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon)
3. [How to resolve the "ADB server didn't ACK" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415746/how-to-resolve-the-adb-server-didnt-ack-error)

Following the links, first try adb start-server from command prompt. When it works, then only try to use ionic emulate android.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. I would love to improve the answer