# react-native Genymotion VM Windows 10

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion, react-native

I am trying to get react-native to work on my Genymotion virtual device.

When I execute react-native run-android in command prompt, I get what's below:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Timeout getting device list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 53.693 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Nothing happens on the VD.
I've alreay tried setting the custom SDK on Genymotion but it hasn't helped.

Comment: check your device using this code 'adb devices'     
and prepare for react-native bridge run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081'    
then 'npm start' and 'react-native run-android'. I hope this will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the answer in this question. You just need to change the path of AndroidSDK on genymotion to the installed android sdk in the settings.

[react native errorTimeout getting device list. When running hello world on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692210/react-native-errortimeout-getting-device-list-when-running-hello-world-on-ubunt)